# How do I use pymongo to connect to an existing document collection/db?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

On the command line, this works:

```
$ mongo
> show dbs
mydatabase   1.0GB
```

However, this does not:

```
$ python    
>>> import pymongo
>>> connection = pymongo.MongoClient()
>>> connection.mydatabase.find()
```

I read through docs here:

http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html

But do not understand how to either...

1. connect to an existing database (using pymongo)
2. query what databases exist in the mongodb connection.

Why can't I access my database?

Comment: Huh, someone recently bumped this Q I don't even remember asking.  This was my first mongo question ever, apparently.  I now do exactly this a billion times a day without even noticing at one time I didn't understand it...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Connect to an existing database](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#making-a-connection-with-mongoclient)

```py
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
connection = MongoClient()
db = connection.mydatabase
```

[List existing databases](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html?highlight=database_names#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient.list_database_names)

```py
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
connection = MongoClient()
# connection.database_names() # depreciated
connection.list_database_names()
```

Answer (score 6):

The question implies user has a *local*  MongoDB. However I found this question trying to connect to a *remote* MongoDB. I think the [tutorial is worth mentioning](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html#making-a-connection-with-mongoclient) (no other answer here mentioned how I can specify the host and the port)

> The above code will connect on the default host and port. We can also specify the host and port explicitly, as follows:

`client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)`

> Or use the MongoDB URI format:

`client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')`

Comment: This question is 6 years old.

Comment: Yes. I think my answer is novel and may help others who came to this question.

Answer (score 2):

`show dbs` and `find()` are totally different commands as such you cannot compare the two.

```
connection.mydatabase.find()
```

Will actually do nothing because you cannot `find()` documents on database level. You are probably looking for:

```
cursor = connection.mydatabase.mycol.find()
```

I am no Python programmer but something like that and the `foreach` the `cursor` var to get your data.

As an added note you will want to replace `mycol` with the collection name that contains your documents.

As for querying for a list of databases you can do something like:

```
databases = connection.mydatabase.command({'listDatabases': 1});
```

As shown here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/listDatabases/#listDatabases

However again I am no Python programmer but this should get you started.

Answer (score 2):

On the python command line:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
connection = MongoClient()  ## connects by default to db at localhost:27017
connection.database_names() ## python binding equivalent to show dbs.
```

Although there doesn't seem to be a wealth of examples, it appears that the bindings are pretty complete within the [Python Driver API Documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

database_names() is deprecated. One can use list_database_names() instead.

mongo_db_url will be something like "mongodb://localhost:27017/". 27017 is deafult port number, replace suitably.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient(<mongo_db_url>)
#or client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
client.list_database_names()
```