# Mongo query in python if I use variable as value

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x, pymongo-2.x

Am trying to find documents from the mongo collection using the following query. `db.collection_name.find({"id" : Id})` where Id is the variable am getting as input. But it doesn't work. If I hard code the value like this `db.collection_name.find({"id" : "1a2b"})` it works. "id" is of string type and am using pymongo to access mongo DB.

code :

```
client = MongoClient("localhost:27017")                
db = client['sample_database']
Id = raw_input("enter id") 
cursor = db.collection_name.find({"id" : Id})
```

Comment: can you please share all of your code before calling find()?

Comment: I have edited with all of my code

Comment: Where did you define your Id? I would expect something like this; Id = str(post_id)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use pymongo to connect to an existing document collection/db?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468992/how-do-i-use-pymongo-to-connect-to-an-existing-document-collection-db)

Comment: Am getting Id as input

Comment: How about `db.collection_name.find({"id": Id.strip()})`?

Answer (score 3):

Try str();

```
Id = str(raw_input("enter id"))
cursor = db.collection_name.find({"id" : Id})
```

Answer (score 2):

This may help you..in python3 it is working..

```
Id = raw_input("enter id: ") 
cursor = db.collection_name.find({"id" : Id})
for i in cursor:
    print(i)
```

there is no require to convert raw_input() to string,Because raw_input() is already get input from user as string..